# How do I CFrame parts?

Tags: lua, coordinate-systems, roblox

I've heard that you can tilt a part by a precise amount using the `.CFrame` property. However, I'm unclear on how to use it. The following code does not work:

```
Workspace.Part.CFrame = CFrame.new(90,0,45)
```

It is not rotating the part by 90 degrees and 45 degrees. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should add more context. Without the *roblox* tag I would have no idea what you were talking about. Also, *roblox* is the name of several products from different companies.

Answer (score 2):

First, use the CFrame.fromEulerAnglesXYZ function to create a new CFrame pointing in the direction you wish. Then, use Vector3 math to move the CFrame into the desired position.
EG.

```
local cframe = CFrame.fromEulerAnglesXYZ(XRADIANS, YRADIANS, ZRADIANS)
cframe = (cframe - cframe.p) + Vector3.new(XPOS,YPOS,ZPOS)
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation states that a [Coordinate Frame (CFrame)](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php/CFrame) constructor that takes 3 parameters is defining a position offset. Therefore, your example code would move the part 90 along the *x*-axis and 45 along the *z*-axis. To perform a rotation as you attempted see the `CFrame.fromEulerAnglesXYZ` function.

Answer (score 1):

The arguments taken specify position, not rotation

Answer (score 0):

I had this trouble too when I was starting to CFrame. They are RADIANS, not DEGREES. I have written a quick CFraming guide on ROBLOX, [here](http://www.roblox.com/Forum/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=30989679).

If you're struggling with radians, you should look at the ROBLOX wiki page on radians to gain a basic understanding: wiki.roblox.com/index.php/Radians

Thanks!

-pighead10

Comment: Link for your guide no longer works.  Could you update?

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Rotates the part by 90 degrees. If you want to change the axis your
-- rotating it on Use a different placement such as CFrame.Angles(math.rad(90),0,0)
Workspace.Part.CFrame = Workspace.Part.CFrame * CFrame.Angles(0, math.rad(90), 0)
```